# error in codeigniter 4 You must set the database table to be used with your query

Tags: codeigniter-4

i am working codeigniter 4. i am trying to fetch data from database by creating method in Model but am getting error

> You must set the database table to be used with your query

even I have mentioned the table name in query builder. i dun know why this is happening ? following is my code

```
 public function Login($values)
    {
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();
  
        $result= $db->table('tbl_adminuser')
                     ->where(['username',$values['username']])
                     ->where(['password',$values['password']])
                     ->get()
                     ->getResult();
        print_r($result);
    }
```

Comment: Please post the complete model in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of getting data from the database.

1. Using the Model file
2. Load db in the controller file

Check both the below types to get data from the database.

**1. Using the Model file**

First, create a User model and mention the name of the database table.

Here is the sample of model file:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models;
     
use CodeIgniter\Model;
    
class UserMasterModel extends Model
{
    protected $table   = 'user_master';
}
```

Then create a controller file and load the model using `use App\Models\UserMasterModel;`.
You should following the below sample of the controller file there is mention load the model and get the data using a model file.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

use App\Models\UserMasterModel;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->db = \Config\Database::connect();
}

public function Login($values){
    $UserMasterModel = new UserMasterModel();
    $result = $UserMasterModel->where('username',$values['username'])
                                ->where('password',$values['password'])
                                ->findAll();
    print_r($result);
}
```

---

**2. Load db in controller file**

When using `\Config\Database::connect()` the controller file looks like below:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $this->user_master = $this->db->table('user_master');
}

public function Login($values){
    $this->user_master->select('*');
    $this->user_master->where('username',$values['username']);
    $this->user_master->where('password',$values['password']);
    $result = $this->user_master->get()->getResult();

    print_r($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create model for users

```
<?php namespace Myth\Auth\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;
use Myth\Auth\Authorization\GroupModel;
use Myth\Auth\Entities\User;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $returnType = User::class;
    protected $useSoftDeletes = false;

    protected $allowedFields = [
        'email', 'username', 'password_hash', 'reset_hash', 'reset_at', 'reset_expires', 'activate_hash',
        'status', 'status_message', 'active', 'force_pass_reset', 'permissions',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'image',
        'address',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'gender',
        'country',
        'city',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    protected $useTimestamps = false;

    protected $validationRules = [
        'email' => 'if_exist|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email,id,{id}]',
        'phone' => 'if_exist|required|is_unique[users.phone,id,{id}]',
        'username' => 'if_exist|required|alpha_numeric_punct|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|is_unique[users.username,id,{id}]',
        'password_hash' => 'if_exist|required',
    ];
    protected $validationMessages = [];
    protected $skipValidation = false;

    protected $afterInsert = ['addToGroup'];

    /**
     * The id of a group to assign.
     * Set internally by withGroup.
     *
     * @var int|null
     */
    protected $assignGroup;

    /**
     * Logs a password reset attempt for posterity sake.
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @param string|null $token
     * @param string|null $ipAddress
     * @param string|null $userAgent
     */
    public function logResetAttempt(string $email, string $token = null, string $ipAddress = null, string $userAgent = null)
    {
        $this->db->table('auth_reset_attempts')->insert([
            'email' => $email,
            'ip_address' => $ipAddress,
            'user_agent' => $userAgent,
            'token' => $token,
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Logs an activation attempt for posterity sake.
     *
     * @param string|null $token
     * @param string|null $ipAddress
     * @param string|null $userAgent
     */
    public function logActivationAttempt(string $token = null, string $ipAddress = null, string $userAgent = null)
    {
        $this->db->table('auth_activation_attempts')->insert([
            'ip_address' => $ipAddress,
            'user_agent' => $userAgent,
            'token' => $token,
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the group to assign any users created.
     *
     * @param string $groupName
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function withGroup(string $groupName)
    {
        $group = $this->db->table('auth_groups')->where('name', $groupName)->get()->getFirstRow();

        $this->assignGroup = $group->id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Clears the group to assign to newly created users.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function clearGroup()
    {
        $this->assignGroup = null;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * If a default role is assigned in Config\Auth, will
     * add this user to that group. Will do nothing
     * if the group cannot be found.
     *
     * @param mixed $data
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function addToGroup($data)
    {
        if (is_numeric($this->assignGroup)) {
            $groupModel = model(GroupModel::class);
            $groupModel->addUserToGroup($data['id'], $this->assignGroup);
        }

        return $data;
    }


}
```

too use model

$model = new usermodel();

$model->asObject()->where('active', '1')->findAll();